# MAMP: MySQL doesn't start

Tags: mysql, macos, mamp

I have MAMP Pro 2.0.5 running on Mac OS X Lion and and the MySQL server doesn't start.

I got the following error message when I attempt to start it:

```
MySQL wasn't able to start. Please check log for more information.
```

I have already tried to kill the mysqld processes but it still doesn't work.

I have also tried to modify the /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/my.cnf file, but everything seems okay.

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you.

See the log below:

```
11/12/11 00:04:32,382 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 351: grep: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,408 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,408 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,411 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,414 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,426 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,426 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,437 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,437 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,442 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,455 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,455 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,455 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,455 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,458 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,461 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,471 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,475 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,479 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,481 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,483 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,488 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,491 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,493 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,495 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,498 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,501 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,505 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,509 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,513 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,516 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,520 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,522 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,525 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,528 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,530 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,533 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,536 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,539 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,542 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,545 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,547 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,550 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,554 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,557 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,559 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,562 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,568 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,572 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,575 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,579 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,582 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 150: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,585 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,588 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,593 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,607 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,607 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 150: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,607 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,607 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,613 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,625 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,629 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 150: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,631 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,634 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,639 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,641 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,643 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 150: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,644 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,646 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,648 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,650 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,652 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 150: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,654 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,656 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,659 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,661 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,663 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 150: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,666 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,668 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,670 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,672 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,000 kernel: nstat_lookup_entry failed: 2
11/12/11 00:04:32,674 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 150: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,676 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 531: hostname: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,678 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 150: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,680 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 103: date: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,680 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro:  mysqld_safe Logging to '/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/.err'.
11/12/11 00:04:32,681 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 582: dirname: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,682 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 608: hostname: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,684 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 150: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,692 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 150: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,695 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 150: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,697 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 150: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,700 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 150: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,703 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 150: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,705 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 150: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,706 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 103: date: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,706 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro:  mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql
11/12/11 00:04:32,707 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 742: rm: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,709 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 150: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,710 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: eval: line 144: syntax error near unexpected token `2'
11/12/11 00:04:32,710 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: eval: line 144: `                 >>  2>&1'
11/12/11 00:04:32,711 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 103: date: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:32,712 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro:  mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/.pid ended
11/12/11 00:04:33,000 kernel: nstat_lookup_entry failed: 2
11/12/11 00:04:42,449 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 351: grep: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,456 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,457 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,459 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,462 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,464 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,466 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,468 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,469 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,471 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,473 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,475 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,476 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,478 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,480 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,481 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,483 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,485 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,487 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,490 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,493 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,497 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,500 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,503 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,506 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,509 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,515 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,519 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,523 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,526 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,529 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,531 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,533 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,535 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,537 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,538 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,540 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,542 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,543 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,546 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,548 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,549 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,551 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,553 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,554 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,556 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,558 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,559 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,561 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,566 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,568 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,570 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,572 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,573 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 150: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,575 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,577 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,580 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,581 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,583 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 150: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,585 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,587 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,589 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,590 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,592 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 150: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,594 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,596 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,598 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,599 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,601 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 150: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,603 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,605 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,606 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,608 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,610 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 150: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,611 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,613 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,615 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,617 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,618 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 150: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,620 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,622 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 168: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,623 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 170: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,625 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 171: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,627 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 150: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,629 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 531: hostname: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,630 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 150: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,631 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 103: date: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,632 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro:  mysqld_safe Logging to '/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/.err'.
11/12/11 00:04:42,633 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 582: dirname: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,634 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 608: hostname: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,636 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 150: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,640 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 150: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,642 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 150: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,645 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 150: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,647 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 150: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,649 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 150: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,651 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 150: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,652 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 103: date: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,652 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro:  mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql
11/12/11 00:04:42,653 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 742: rm: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,655 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 150: sed: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,655 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: eval: line 144: syntax error near unexpected token `2'
11/12/11 00:04:42,655 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: eval: line 144: `                 >>  2>&1'
11/12/11 00:04:42,656 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe: line 103: date: command not found
11/12/11 00:04:42,656 [0x0-0xa70a7].de.appsolute.mamppro:  mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/.pid ended
```

Comment: I'm not sure regarding this but there are a lot of "command not found" entries in your log. are you able to call the commands from the terminal?

Answer (score 5):

For those of us who are visually oriented, check the Activity Monitor for the mysqld process and KILL IT... dead, d-e-a-d. ;)

Here's how:

1.Search Finder for Activity Monitor on your Mac.
2.Open it.
3.Search for a process called“mysqld“.
4.Click on that process and “Quit Process” that bastard.

Comment: mine just immediately relaunches

Answer (score 1):

`mysld_safe` is a shell script that use some unix commands (like `grep`, `sed`, etc.) to start the mysql daemon, the problem is that the script can not found those commands, there are usually on the `/bin` or `/usr/bin` directories, check that those directories (or the directory where the commands that said "command not found" are installed) are in then `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with MAMP Pro 2.1.1 when my system shutdown due to battery drain. I resolved this problem by removing the old pid file locate under `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql`

Try this command:

`mv /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid.bak`